# Change page background color with each route using ReactJS and React Router?

Tags: jquery, css, reactjs

How can I change the browsers background color when going to a new route, using ReactJS and React Router? See my EDIT's below for ideas I figured out along the way:

I can get this working on the `<div>` in each page view, but I need it working on the full background so the full browser window shows the background.

I playing with jQuery, but wondering if that's even the right way to solve this? I'm also trying to use `React.DOM.body`, but not getting it working:

```
  render: function() {
    return (
      <div>
        React.DOM.body( {style: background-color: "green"} )
        <MyHeader />
          <this.props.activeRouteHandler/>
      </div>
    );
  }
```

**EDIT 1:** 
I got this working, but... means I have to duplicate this CSS class for every page I want to have a different background. To use just wrap each return with: `<div className="my-signup-bkg">`:

```
.my-signup-bkg {
    /*To support older browsers*/
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;

    /* Set the height to match that of the viewport. */
    height: 100vh;

    /* Set the width to match that of the viewport. */
    width: 100vw;

    background-image: url("../images/mod-yellow-bkg.jpg");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: 100%; 
}
```

**EDIT 2:**
Here's another way, that I like this better, it requires fewer lines of CSS and is more explicit in the ReactJS component. I set this CSS on a DIV:

```
.my-page-text {
    /*height: inherit;*/
    padding: 8% 5% 5% 3%;
    /*top: 55px;*/

    /*To support older browsers*/
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;

    /* Set the height to match that of the viewport. */
    height: 100vh;

    /* Set the width to match that of the viewport. */
    width: 100vw;

    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: 100%; 
}
```

And use this in my ReactJS component:

```
var MyLoginView = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    var style = { backgroundImage: 'url("static/images/mod-yellow-bkg.jpg")' };

    return (
      <div className="my-page-text" style={style}>
          Do something.
      </div>
    );
  }
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure that the root component that React renders with `React.renderComponent(<Root>, ...)` covers the full screen. Now simply manage the state in the `Root#render()` function like this:

```
getInitialState: function () {
  return { color: "white" };
},

changeColor: function () {
  this.setState({ color: "black" });
},

render: function () {
  var style = { backgroundColor: this.state.color };

  return (
    <div id="fullscreen" style={style}>
       <a onClick={this.changeColor}>change</a>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Note that the root component, `div#fullscreen`, must cover the full screen.

Comment: Thanks... Also see my EDITS above with some other ways to solve this.

Comment: I posted separate question about using React.DOM here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25474803/trying-to-use-react-dom-to-set-body-styles

Comment: How do you make the div cover the whole screen? At most I'm only able to cover most of the screen