# Trying to use React.DOM to set body styles

Tags: javascript, reactjs

How can I use React.DOM to change styles on HTML `body`?

I tried this code and it's not working:

```
var MyView = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    return (
      <div>
        React.DOM.body.style.backgroundColor = "green";
        Stuff goes here.
      </div>
    );
  }
});
```

If you execute this from the browsers console it works (but I need it working in ReactJS code):
`document.body.style.backgroundColor = "green";`

Also see this question for similar but different solution:
[Change page background color with each route using ReactJS and React Router?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25473414/change-page-background-color-with-each-route-using-reactjs-and-react-router)

Comment: `React.DOM` is for creating React components. It doesn't really let access existing DOM nodes.`React.DOM.body` is a constructor, it's not a reference to `document.body`.

Comment: Got it, your answer makes sense, but in this case, couldn't it be used to 'construct' a new style for the backgroundColor style tag?

Answer (score 131, accepted):

Assuming your body tag isn't part of another React component, just change it as usual:

```
document.body.style.backgroundColor = "green";
//elsewhere..
return (
  <div>
    Stuff goes here.
  </div>
);
```

It's recommended to put it at `componentWillMount` method, and cancel it at `componentWillUnmount`:

```
componentWillMount: function(){
    document.body.style.backgroundColor = "green";
}

componentWillUnmount: function(){
    document.body.style.backgroundColor = null;
}
```

Comment: On navigating straight to the page React crashes, because document is not defined yet.

Comment: Why to have `componentWillUnmount`?

Comment: @DhavalJardosh Cause you want your body to come back to it's normal "state" when the component that changed body's style unmounts.

Comment: what I see is, whenever we leave the page or go away from that component, it automatically clears the state.
Please correct me if I'm wrong, and thank you for responding.

Comment: Except this isn't the state. It's DOM manipulation. This will stay the same when you leave the component, unless you set it back on ComponentWillUnmount

Comment: More recent versions of React will give you a warning for using `componentWillMount`, in order to bypass this you can use `componentDidMount` instead.

Answer (score 22):

With functional components and useEffect hook :

```
useEffect(()  => {
    document.body.classList.add('bg-black');

    return () => {
        document.body.classList.remove('bg-black');
    };
});
```

Answer (score 4):

A good solution to load multiple atributes from a js class to the document body can be:

```
componentWillMount: function(){
    for(i in styles.body){
        document.body.style[i] = styles.body[i];
    }
},
componentWillUnmount: function(){
    for(i in styles.body){
        document.body.style[i] = null;
    }
},
```

And after you write your body style as long as you want:

```
var styles = {
    body: {
        fontFamily: 'roboto',
        fontSize: 13,
        lineHeight: 1.4,
        color: '#5e5e5e',
        backgroundColor: '#edecec',
        overflow: 'auto'
    }
}
```

Comment: Why `componentWillUnmount`?

Comment: @DhavalJardosh so that side effects occur and the component is cleaned up when it unmounts from the DOM

Answer (score 4):

The best way to load or append extra classes is by adding the code in componentDidMount().

Tested with ***react and meteor*** :

```
componentDidMount() {
    var orig = document.body.className;
    console.log(orig);  //Just in-case to check if your code is working or not
    document.body.className = orig + (orig ? ' ' : '') + 'gray-bg'; //Here gray-by is the bg color which I have set
}
componentWillUnmount() {
    document.body.className = orig ;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This is what I ended up using.

```
import { useEffect } from "react";

export function useBodyStyle(style: any){
    useEffect(()=>{
        for(var key in style){
            window.document.body.style[key as any] = style[key];
        }
        return () => {
            window.document.body.style[key as any] = '';
        }
    }, [style])
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Even if you can set body styles from react with the provided answer, I prefer if a component is only responsible for setting its own style.

In my case there was an alternative solution. I needed to change the body backgroundColor. This could easily be achieved without changing the body style in a react component.

First I added this style to the index.html header.

```
<style>
    html, body, #react-app {
        margin: 0;
        height: 100%;
    }
</style>
```

Then, in my outermost component, I set the backgroundColor to the needed value and the height to 100%.