# Style <body> and <html> from React?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I can style a component in reactJS like this

```
        const buttonStyle = {
            marginTop: "10px"
        };

<button class="btn btn-block btn-success" style={buttonStyle}>Success</button>
```

I want do change the body tag from one component but not from the rest.

This is not working (because body is in index.html)

```
<body style={bodyStyle}>
```

How do I do?

Comment: Why not define that in `CSS` ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25474803/trying-to-use-react-dom-to-set-body-styles, though, I would also recommend defining it in `CSS`.

Comment: How do I define it in CSS if I want to have css on the <body> when I render one page/component but not the rest?

Answer (score 0):

[react-body-classname](https://github.com/PactCoffee/react-body-classname) can be used to have the body `style` modified as any other react component.