# Different background color for different pages in web application

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

I am working on a react project to make a web application. I have a login screen and the main screen which comes after user logs in. These are the only two components in my project. I want to have blue body background for login page and white body color/background for main page. I read on few threads that

```
body#page1{
   background-color:#000;
}
```

This will help by giving id to body tag of each page. But I cannot include the body tag in my react component as it is not allowed. So how can I achieve to have different body colors on two different pages.

Comment: just use #page1{background-color:##00} and dont include the body tag

Comment: Going off of what @thatOneGuy just said, you dont always have to style the body. You can "fake it" by styling a div and giving that element the needed height.

Comment: I gave the div 100% height but it doesn't cover the complete screen and if I ll give the height in px then it will fail in screens of different size.

Comment: are you using jquery? can you try using the .parent() tag?

Comment: No I am not using jquery. And I am not able to understand .parent() things you are saying.

Comment: Its a jquery tag. Selects the parent of the current element. Havent worked on react so it was merely a suggestion

Comment: This might help
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25474803/trying-to-use-react-dom-to-set-body-styles

Answer (score 1):

Have a div and give it top, bottom, left, right 0px and position absolute so it will cover the full screen regardless of size.

```
<div className="page-one-bg">
   //all code of page 1
</div>
```

In your css file

```
.page-one-bg {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    background: #000;
}
```