# Modal present but body still scrolls

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, modal-dialog

I am working in React and attempting to stop my body from scrolling while my modal is open.

I have seen multiple posts about this, all suggesting to add `overflow: hidden` as the solution, however I can't seem to get this to work.

*FYI - My example is a simplistic representation with a modal forced to be open and no dynamic variables in place for the time being. I am just trying to figure this test case out so I can integrate into my code.*

Component

```
export default function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App modal-open">
      <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
      <br />
      ... <!-- Added multiple <br/>s to force scrollable body -->
      <h2>Start editing to see some magic happen!</h2>

      <div className="modal-container">
        <div className="modal-content">My modal</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

CSS

```
.modal-open {
  background: red;
  overflow: hidden;
  overflow-y: hidden;
}

.modal-container {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
}
.modal-content {
  position: fixed;
  background: white;
  width: 80%;
  height: auto;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

[Here is my codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/goofy-einstein-oul32?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To solve that you can add a `body` selector on your css and put `overflow:hidden`.

[edited codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/eager-thunder-jgsf4?file=/src/styles.css)

Then you can conditionally add a logic however you want.

Comment: Where/how would one add conditional logic around the body's css?

Comment: this post can hel you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25474803/trying-to-use-react-dom-to-set-body-styles

Comment: Awesome, thanks!
It's something I'd done before but Friday-syndrom has fried my brain.

Comment: this link also is helpful for use cases https://brettdewoody.com/modifying-body-attributes-in-react/