# An alternative design without a scrollbar caused by padding

Tags: css, sass, scroll, flexbox

The code that appears below creates the following layout:

[image]

The important part is that the content, although centered on the screen when not overflowing, never overlaps the navbar and has its own scrollbar:

[image]

The problem is that this layout is achieved with the help of padding (marked by a comment in the code below), which results in the additional scrollbar on the right of the screen.

How can I design the same layout that would have only one scrollbar - the one in the content?

Please note that the solution should not break the following details:

- The rounded corners and the shadow.
- The title in the content block not participating in scrolling.
- The image covering the whole scrollable content, so it scrolls together with the content.

In addition, it would be great if this can be achieved without as many nested `div`'s as I have right now.

**Edit:** I am ready to go with the suggestion of @JHeth in the comments section. However, I would still be interested if someone can come up with an alternative design that does not rely on padding for centering.

Here is the code ([CodePen](https://codepen.io/mgoldenb/pen/WNZxXBj?editors=1100)):

```
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

html { 
  font-size: 62.5%;
}

:root {
  --navbar-height: 3rem;
}

.navbar {
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 2rem;
  line-height: var(--navbar-height);
  background-color: lightgreen;
}
.centering {
  position: absolute;
  inset: var(--navbar-height) 0 0 0;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  & .auto-margin {
    margin: auto;
    
    // For scrollable content
    display: flex;
    max-height: 100%;
    padding-bottom: calc(var(--navbar-height)); // Causes scrolling
  }
}

.content-block {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  .title {
    font-size: 2rem;
    position: sticky;
  }
  .content-outer-container {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    overflow-y: auto;
    border-radius: 1em;
    box-shadow: 0 1em 2em rgba(black, 0.4);
    .content-container {
      width: 300px;
      overflow-y: auto;
      .content {
        position: relative;
        padding: 1em;
        &:before {
          content: "";
          z-index: -1;
          position: absolute;
          top: 0;
          left: 0;
          right: 0;
          height: 100%;
          background-position: center;
          background-image: 
            url(http://www.freegreatpicture.com/files/147/18380-hd-color-background-wallpaper.jpg);
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

```
<div class="navbar">An Amazing Navbar</div>
<div class="centering">
  <div class="auto-margin">
    <div class="content-block">
      <div class="title">My Title</div>
      <div class="content-outer-container">
        <div class="content-container">
          <div class="content">
            <h1>Line1</h1>
            <h1>Line2</h1>
            <h1>Line3</h1>
            <h1>Line4</h1>
            <h1>Line5</h1>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You could add `overflow-y: hidden` to your html ruleset.

Comment: And you can't conditionally add the single rule or a class that contains the overflow rule to your html tag on this page only? Something like this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25474803/trying-to-use-react-dom-to-set-body-styles

Comment: @JHeth I had deleted my comment, since I realized that I could always add a `div` that occupies the whole screen, has `overflow-y: auto` and serves as a parent of all other content on that page. Also, please see the **Edit** to the question.

Comment: For your edit you could make the inset on the `.centering` div be 0 for all values and then add a margin top using your navbar-height variable. This removes the need for overflow-y: hidden. Here's those changes on your pen https://codepen.io/JHeth/pen/yLzJvQY?editors=1100

Comment: @JHeth Nope, now it is not centered with respect to the *whole* viewport height when not overflowing.

Answer (score -1):

simply remove `max-height:100%;` to `.centering .auto-margin` and it'll works!

```
.centering .auto-margin {
    margin: auto;
    display: flex;
    /* max-height: 100%; */
    padding-bottom: calc(var(--navbar-height));
}
```

Comment: This does not remove the side scrollbar. In addition, it breaks scrolling in the content `div`.